# Has language begun to converge in the age of mass media?

Tags: language-evolution, mass-media

I understand that this question may be perceived as a bit broad for this site, but I've decided to post it anyway.  I figured that with the number of linguists, linguaphiles, and all-around language geeks on this site, I might get a rather intelligent (brief) answer pointing me to more detailed discussions on the subject.

It is my belief that **one of the ways** language evolves is similar to all other forms of evolution.  Certain usages fall into and out of favor depending upon local necessity, and geographic separation can often lead to wide divergence in common languages (accents, sentence structure, etc.).  One need only to look at the wide variations in English spoken in England, Australia, Canada, and the USA for proof of this divergence.

Clearly loan words and other factors have a strong influence on the evolution of a language, but I would like to set those aside for a different discussion.

I have long theorized that with the advent of mass media, and particularly the growth of the internet and social media, that language is now passed without the restrictions imposed by geographic separation.  I think this should be a fairly self-evident statement, but as an example:  *If Hollywood movies are viewed world-wide, then American English and idioms should be spread world-wide to no small degree.*

So, after that long-winded introduction.  My question:

Is there any evidence that language (particularly English) is undergoing convergent evolution, where we are all beginning to speak more similarly to one another since the advent of mass media?  Has this been a focus of study?

While the process is *slightly* different in the biological sense, I think that [convergent evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution) is an apt term here.

Comment: This is a duplicate of something that was written on a pub wall in the 1450s.

Comment: @RyeBread Where do you think I came up with the question?

Comment: I wonder if Barrie or FF answered it already then?

Comment: No, no evidence at all. You're totally out in left field; language evolution doesn't work that way at all, and languages are not converging. Non-English speakers are learning more languages and getting smarter, but that's nothing new.

Comment: @JohnLawler So, you don't think that idioms are becoming more universal?  I've heard AmE creeping into other dialects before:  especially in the form of AAVE terms being picked up from rap, etc.  You wouldn't characterize that as converging?

Comment: Languages borrow words when needed. Also nothing new. Language is far more than words.

Comment: @JohnLawler That does make sense, of course.  But, how else would you describe the divergence in accents, terminology, sentence structure, etc.  Why would it be left-field to wonder if the opposite could happen by the free-flowing communication leading to an unprecedented continuity.

Comment: @JohnLawler in seeing your answer and that below I realized that I was coming off as believing this to be the *only* manner of evolution.  That wasn't my intent, I've revised above, and I'd appreciate your input without that red herring thrown in.

Comment: There is a vast literature of facts about how languages change, and in what ways. No speculation is necessary; facts are available. Certainly languages do not undergo evolution like organisms, because languages are acquired during life and can't be passed on genetically. They're not Mendelian, but Lamarckian, and not the same kind of thing at all. Have a look at David Crystal's _Cambridge Encyclopedia of Language,_ or at Larry Trask's _Historical Linguistics_, before you speculate. As Goethe said, "Thinking is more interesting than knowing, but less interesting than looking."

Comment: @JohnLawler So, you object to my characterization of it being *convergent evolution*?  Of course it cannot be passed on genetically, that would be ludicrous.  I was merely using the phenomenon of geographic isolation that leads to the genetic form of divergent evolution as an easy to understand (for a biological science type like myself) way to explain my thoughts.  I'm just not sensing if its the metaphor or the whole concept of isolation leading to evolution you object to.  I will take a look at those sources.  Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: Geographic isolation is one of many factors; borrowing sounds, structures, metaphors, gods, idioms, inflections, derivations, and other features -- which might be analogous to gene sharing among bacteria and archaea -- certainly complicates the picture. I don't object to your metaphor of evolution, just the assumption that it will homogenize language. There's no evidence for that; it just seems to be normal wishful thinking, the sorts of beliefs that led to Volakpük and Lojban. One can see how successful they've been.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, that actually *does* answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion language does not only evolve the way plants evolve. There is also influx of other languages which I regard as not being part of evolution.

When the romans invaded Britain, they brought a huge amount of roman influence. As a consequence of this, you can now observe similarities between english and other romanic languages. When the Anglo-Saxons invaded Britain, they brought their language with them. Because of the Anglo-Saxons you can now observe similarities between english and germanic-based languages (please excuse this vague term). So, now you can use for the same thing a word with a roman root or a word with a germanic root.

If you lived in roman times or shortly afterwards, you could observe a language convergence in the roman world. If you lived in the early medievals, there was divergence going on compared to the roman times.

There are also efforts taken to not only translate loan word from other languages but create new words to replace the loan words. The frensh created the word [courriel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courriel) for the word email. So, that's also a kind of divergent evolution. The icelandinc language is famous for its language purism. So, the existence of global mass media does not automatically cause language convergence. This differs among languages and over time.

Comment: To be certain, the borrowing of words is a factor in the evolution of language. Perhaps I should have included it above.  I never meant to insinuate that divergence and convergence were the *only* forces. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Once again, it is not a matter of opinion, any more than evolution by natural selection is. Opinions are useless when facts are available.